# Use Google Docs API to download file of any type

Tags: java, google-docs-api

Is it possible to download files of any type from Google Docs using the Google Docs API? (jpg, zip, txt)

I can figure out how to download word, powerpoint, and excel files but want to be able to upload and download any type of file to Google Docs. I know it is possible to do this with the online uploader but can't seem to get the downloading part to work with the API.

I'm using the Java wrapper to the API. Is it possible to use the Java version of the API to download all file types?

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question Alex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last answer was written, that API is deprecated. There's sample Java code on the [Google Dev page for the (newer) Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) for managing downloads from Google Docs.

This handles a large variety of MIME types.

Answer (score 1):

See this page http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

and this for specifically downloading documents and files
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocsAndFiles

The document listing XML returned by google has file type and the URL to download the file in the  node. You can use the URL to download the file contents.